# Notification Service for Pusher in Angular 2

Tags: angular, events, notifications, pusher

I am learning how to implement a notification service for my pusher notifications. I basically want to keep track of the notifications from pusher. Currently, i am able to receive the pusher notifications from the pusher channel but after i click on the it disappears/ destroy. As a matter of fact, I want to display the notifications fired by pusher on my application in a list so i can keep track of them.The notifications should be listed on the event.html page. 
**Question : How can the notification service work with the pusher functionality to achieve what i have explained above?**

**Notification Service**

```
export class NotificationService {
  private _notifications = new Subject<Notification>();

  public noteAdded = this._notifications.asObservable();

  public add(notification: Notification) {
      this._notifications.next(notification);
}
```

**Notication Model**

```
export class Notification{
    constructor(
        public type: string = '',
        public message: string = '') {}
}
```

**Notification**

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'notifications',
    template:`
    <div class="notifications">
        <div (click)="hide(note)" class="{{ note.type }}"
                *ngFor="let note of _notes">
            {{ note.message }}
        </div>
    </div>
    `,
    providers:[NotificationService]
})

export class NotificationComponent{
    private _notes: Notification[];

    constructor(private _notifications: NotificationService) {
        this._notes = new Array<Notification>();

        _notifications.noteAdded.subscribe(note => {
            this._notes.push(note);
            setTimeout(() => { this.hide.bind(this)(note) }, 3000);
        });
    }

    private hide(note) {
        let index = this._notes.indexOf(note);

        if (index >= 0) {
            this._notes.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**event.html**

```
 <notifications></notifications>
```

**event.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'pusher',
    templateUrl: 'event.html',
    providers:[HttpService, NotificationService]
})
export class pusherComponent{
    constructor(private httpService:HttpService, private router:Router, private elementRef:ElementRef, private _notes:NotificationService) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src ="src/app/js/pusher.js";
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
    }
 }
```

Comment: You could reduce the length of your question by about 1/3 by removing white space ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, i just did and hope this is okay  ;-)

Comment: I don't see any change related to white space.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer this should be quite better i suppose

Comment: While this is not exactly answer to your problem, yet, if you are trying to stack up the notification and even keep them if the parent view has been changed, its is something that is done by this already
http://flauc.github.io/angular2-notifications/, since the project is on git, you may want to check the source on how to do it, yourself

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, can you please explain to me how the notification service is intergrated with the pusher. Certainly, i think the notification service above is quite structured well and i am able to receive notifications from pusher as well. But then, how i would i let my notification service read the notification fired from the pusher? my worry now